# PHPUnit load test suite with recursive directory expression

Tags: phpunit, expression

I am trying to define my `phpunit.xml` configuration with a custom test suite, which loads all Unit tests in desired folder recursively.

Folder path examples:

```
tests/path/Unit/MyTest.php
tests/path/path/Unit/MyTest.php
tests/path/path/path/Unit/MyTest.php
tests/path/path/path/path/Unit/MyTest.php
...
tests/{.../}/Unit/MyTest.php
```

I can define my suite like this:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Unit Test Suite">
        <directory>tests/*/Unit</directory>
        <directory>tests/*/*/Unit</directory>
        <directory>tests/*/*/*/Unit</directory>
        <directory>tests/*/*/*/*/Unit</directory>
        ...
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Is there a way to iterate over all sub-folders that my expression would be only a single line?

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need to mention all the subdirectories. You just have to have `<directory>tests</directory>`

Comment: @akond there are some tests I want to exclude (Functional) :)

Comment: why don't you use `<exclude>` then?

Comment: @akond I believe the same expression is needed to use in `<exclude>` in my case, as `Functional` is also could be in any level of sub-folder. I gave `Unit` and `Functional` just as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I should use `**` in this case. I'd try to name directories the same inside different sub-directories, so that `**` would work everywhere.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit colors="true" backupGlobals="false">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Test Suite">
      <directory>tests</directory>
      <exclude>**/Functional</exclude>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

or if you'd rather include things:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit colors="true" backupGlobals="false">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Test Suite">
      <directory>**/Unit</directory>
      <exclude>*</exclude>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```